# I want to make a super OP dragon that breathes fire underwater

Tags: science-based, creature-design, dragons, urban-fantasy

I want to create a super Over-Powered dragon that can:

1. Breathe fire
2. Breathe fire under water
3. Not harm itself while breathing fire (either above water or under water)

I would like answers that are as scientifically accurate as possible, as I am creating a world that's like a modern medieval age with dragons.

Comment: First of all, MoonStar, please take a look at the [help] and [tour]! These resources will help you understand what this forum is all about and how to write good questions & answers. You have a good basic idea, but you're asking too many questions. You need to focus on one problem and one question.

Comment: Hello again MoonStar. Since this is worldbuilding, the answer to all your questions is simply YES. You can do whatever you want. There are already many questions based off of making dragons realistic, please have a look at those. Please limit your question to only ONE question at a time. Each of the questions you asked could form a valid worldbuilding question in its own right and it would be much more beneficial for you to ask them individually and interact with the community to figure out your requirements.

Comment: Hi MoonStar.  Are you the same MoonStar as the one who posted the other question?  When a question is put on hold, we want people to edit the original question, not ask a new one.  Do you still have access to the other account?  I'd like to help you get your accounts and questions sorted out so you've got one question on one account, if possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of unclear what you are trying to get, however some light research can go a long way.

1. Fire needs fuel, oxygen, and heat in order to survive. Oxygen is prevalent in the air outside of the body, as well as would be inhaled into the body. However, if the fire is created inside the body, then perhaps the lungs would need to be larger. The next thing we need is heat. Now, the inside of a warm-blooded body already packs a lot of heat, but to actually spark this flame, the dragon would need bio-electricity, perhaps or the fuel used to make the fire could be pyrophorus to just skip this step. Finally, the actual fuel used to make the fire. There are many pyrophorus materials that can light up on impact with the air, but I found that potassium also reacts violently with water to answer your second question.
2. In order to make the dragon resistant to it's own fire, you could have a layer of argon covering it. under the argon, however could just be fire-resistant hide or scales.

The only problem I see with this is how the dragon would actually obtain all of these metals. You said that it was sort of modern, so maybe the dragon could steal the metals from research labs and factories that contain it?